What are all the "special" suru verbs?
Some Japanese verbs are composed of a sino-morpheme followed by す、する、ずる、or じる. They conjugate differently from normal する verbs, and (as far as I know) they're always one kanji rather than two.
Some examples:

訳す
達する
禁ずる
信じる

Wikipedia has a section describing what these verbs are and some conjugation information, but is there a complete list of these words?

Do things like ググる count?

I can add 興じる and 乗じる.

@KarlKnechtel - If Google was made in China, it might. The question clearly says "sino-morpheme."

存じる (comment length)

In the export of the Japanese Wiktionary from January 2023 I found these entries containing 1 Kanji followed by jiru/zuru/suru/su.
As for final -su and -jiru, I manually excluded Wago verbs with those Okurigana.

ずる

感ずる,
通ずる,
論ずる,
応ずる,
損ずる,
訓ずる,

す (manually cross-checked with English Wiktionary to exclude Wago verbs in -su)

鎖す,
愛す,
服す,
食す,
死す,
託す,
托す,
属す,
嘱す,
課す,
科す,
化す,
架す,
屈す,
度す,
解す,
処す,

じる (manually cross-checked with English Wiktionary to exclude Wago verbs in -jiru)

信じる,
感じる,
通じる,
投じる,
論じる,
愧じる,
羞じる,
交じる,
報じる,
講じる,
動じる,
招じる,
念じる,
応じる,
高じる,
禁じる,
命じる,
損じる,
変じる,
存じる,
任じる,
案じる,
訓じる,

する

愛する,
科する,
課する,
嘉する,
好する,
掬する,
有する,
関する,
属する,
死する,
食する,
嘱する,
託する,
托する,
対する,
発する,
議する,
記する,
接する,
没する,
揺する,
益する,
評する,
面する,
決する,
列する,
復する,
罰する,
得する,
察する,
窮する,
称する,
熱する,
抗する,
扮する,
損する,
令する,
存する,
類する,
要する,
略する,
介する,
資する,
呈する,
脱する,
反する,
圧する,
敵する,
適する,
題する,
黙する,
化する,
際する,
擁する,
表する,
比する,
滅する,
失する,
品する,
征する,
制する,
了する,
徹する,
帰する,
会する,
労する,
瀕する,
架する,
画する,
草する,
賞する,
解する,
蔵する,
廃する,
老する,
便する,
供する,
稿する,
偏する,
臆する,
宣する,
給する,
検する,
慨する,
帯する,
誅する,
医する,
航する,
執する,
概する,
狂する,
貶する,
貧する,
委する,
製する,
体する,
利する,
証する,
漁する,
賭する,
療する,
策する,
逸する,
擬する,
嫁する,
駕する,
賀する,
喫する,
浴する,
詣する,
寓する,
熟する,
弄する,
排する,
秘する,
律する,
目する,
毒する,
模する,
叙する,
辞する,
絶する,
堕する,
奏する,
謝する,
激する,
燗する,
号する,
瞑する,
配する,
着する,
算する,
期する,
遇する,
婚する,
倍する,
冠する,
住する,
聘する,
産する,
修する,
則する,
処する,
験する,
持する,
博する,
饗する,
書する,
僭する,
役する,
即する,
賛する,
参する,
訳する,
達する,
諾する,
潮する,
陣する,
挺する,
害する,
刑する,
印する,
銘する,
勒する,
選する,
弔する,
節する,
魅する,
合する,
御する,
典する,
慰する,
侍する,
陪する,
婬する,
淫する,

Not sure 揺する belongs here. And 値する is a kun'yomi.

@aguijonazo I removed 値する (あたいする).
揺する is "funny" because it's given as ゆする (Kun'yomi) in Wiktionary, but also says "Etymology: From Middle Chinese 搖 (MC yew)."

Not an exhaustive list but I can add 愛する, 案ずる, 感じる, 生じる to the list

Is Is 察する another example?

You can download snapshot of JMdict / EDICT dictionary and locally grep it, or use Jisho.org (which uses data from JMdict and other sources).

Snapshots of JMdict / EDICT, JMnedict / ENAMDICT and some other dictionaries at https://www.edrdg.org/pub/Nihongo/ are updated every day at 03:30 UTC:
JMdict.gz (XML format, with some additional data)
edict2u.gz


$ grep vs-c edict2u
...
$ grep vs-s edict2u
...
$ grep vz edict2u
...


Jisho.org (search options):
#vs-c
#vs-s
#vz


